# How to change part of HTML href elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an href I'd like to change with javascript:

```
<a href="http://YOURSUBDOMAIN.foxycart.com/cart?name=ITEMNAME&price=YOURPRICE">Add to Cart</a>
```

I need to change the ITEMNAME and YOURPRICE part of the href with javascript variables. What's the best way to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the href attribute :)

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://YOURSUBDO..." >Add to cart</a>
<script>
    var itemName = "poney";
    var price = 100;
    document.getElementById('myLink").href = "http://YOURSUBDOMAIN.foxycart.com/cart?name=" + itemName + "&price=" + price;
</script>
```

Comment: src attribute of ANCHOR element..? where do you see the src..?

Comment: if variable price's value is assigned by another function and then I pass the variable into the href, I get price as being "undefined", what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Well there's probably a problem with your variable. Add a console.log(myPrice) to see its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script lang='javascript'>  
    function change_url(item_name, item_price)
    {
        new_url = 'http://YOURSUBDOMAIN.foxycart.com/cart?';
        new_url+= 'name='+item_name+'&price='+item_price;
        document.getElementById('your_link').src = new_url;
                    alert('Your new link for the page : '+document.getElementById('your_link').src);
    }
</script>

<a id='your_link' href="http://YOURSUBDOMAIN.foxycart.com/cart?name=ITEMNAME&price=YOURPRICE">Add to Cart</a>
<input type='text' id='test_input' onchange="change_url('New Product',200)" />
```