# Javascript, change middle part of a link

Tags: javascript, input, hyperlink, field, href

I have a list of items that are links, and I want to only a part of the link to change based on a input field.

For example:

```
http://www.myexamplepage.com/?q=%22ITEM1%22&sort=date&from=2017-01-11&to=2017-01-20
```

So if I want to do this:

```
<form><input id="date"><input></form>

<a href="http://www.myexamplepage.com/?q=%22ITEM1%22&sort=date&from=XXXXXX&to=XXXXXX">

<a href="http://www.myexamplepage.com/?q=%22ITEM2%22&sort=date&from=XXXXXX&to=XXXXXX">

<a href="http://www.myexamplepage.com/?q=%22ITEM3%22&sort=date&from=XXXXXX&to=XXXXXX">
```

Where XXXXXX changes depending on the value i input in the input field. Because another part of the link changes (ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3 etc.) this solution for example, will not work: [How to change part of HTML href elements with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438090/how-to-change-part-of-html-href-elements-with-javascript) all solutions I find are like this one, or they completely changes everything after XXXXXX in the link.

Any tips?

Comment: Also, your HTML is invalid: `<input>` is not a valid input element.

Comment: Yeah it was just an example and pretty much beyond the point.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out the part of the url string using `indexOf` and `subString`.
Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/xdckhvyp/

```
var string = 'http://www.myexamplepage.com/?q=%22ITEM3%22&sort=date&from=XXXXXX&to=2017-01-20';

var startingPoint = string.indexOf('from=') + 5;
var endingPoint = string.indexOf('&to');

string.substring(startingPoint, endingPoint);
```